# How do I find click event of anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find click event of anchor tag,

I tried like following but no luck , I did any common mistake

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {


             $('a').on('click', function () {
                 alert('Got you');
             });

         });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="single-page.html#a1">Link text</a>
<a href="single-page.html#a2">Link text</a>
</body>
```

Comment: have you included jquery lib ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sJ9Yz/

Comment: please check your console, any error?

Comment: Are anchors added dynamically?

Comment: On a positive note, I've learn about the shorthand for `$(document).ready` (I had to look it up to make sure that wasn't the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in your code.

May be you are using older version of jquery, which doesn't have `.on()`. It was added only in the version 1.7

Try:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    alert('Got you');
 });
```

Or:

```
$('a').bind('click' , function(){
   alert('Got you');
});
```